# Annotations and intellisense of parameters of custom functions in Excel

Tags: ms-office, office-js, custom-functions-excel

I'm making [custom functions in Excel by JavaScript API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/custom-functions-overview).

I added a function as follows.

```
/**
 * Add two numbers
 * @customfunction
 * @param {number} first First number
 * @param {number} second Second number
 * @returns {number} The sum of the two numbers.
 */
export function add(first, second) {
  return first + second;
}
```

I can see that `Add two numbers` is displayed in the following case. However, I don't see where annotations such as `first`, `second`, `First number`, `Second number`, `The sum of the two numbers.` are displayed. Does anyone know what's their purpose?

[image]

Additionally, what is useful is the intellisense of parameters of a function as follows, does anyone know how to enable this for custom functions?

[image]